# code with dictionaries raises a KeyError: ' '

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I run into trouble while doing my assignment, here's the question:

> Write, test and document (internally) a Python program to solve the following problem:
>
> For each student in a class, the student number and six test marks (out of 100) are given as input. The number of students is not known. Compute and output the following:
>
> for each student
>   the final mark out of 100. The first three marks are worth 20% each and the last three marks are worth 15%, 15% and 10%, respectively. Write a function which, given the six marks, computes and returns the final mark out of 100.
>   the letter grade corresponding to the mark. Write a function which, given the final mark out of 100, computes and returns the letter grade according to the following table:...
>
> for the class
>   the average final mark.
>   the highest final mark.
>   the total number of As, Bs, Cs, Ds and Fs.

I've written up a code for it, albeit not finished yet:

```
#student_name: Zhiwei Liu; student_number: 201604402

students={}
student_number= ''
def main():
    global student_number = input('student number: ')
    '''For python 2: 
    test_marks=[int(n) for n in raw_input('Enter test marks: ').split()]'''
    #For python 3:
    test_marks=[int(n) for n in input('Enter test marks: ').split()]
    students[student_number]={}
    students[student_number]['final_mark']=0.2*test_marks[0]+0.2*test_marks[1]+0.2*test_marks[2]+0.15*test_marks[3]+0.15*test_marks[4]+0.1*test_marks[5]
    if 80<=students[student_number]['final_mark']<=100:
        students[student_number]['letter_grade']='A'
    elif 65<=students[student_number]['final_mark']<=79:
        students[student_number]['letter_grade']='B'
    elif 55<=students[student_number]['final_mark']<=64:
        students[student_number]['letter_grade']='C'
    elif 50<=students[student_number]['final_mark']<=54:
        students[student_number]['letter_grade']='D'
    elif 0<=students[student_number]['final_mark']<=49:
        students[student_number]['letter_grade']='F'
main()
count=1
continue_=input('Continue? y/n')    
while continue_.lower() == 'y':
    average=0
    main()
    count+=1
    average+=students[student_number]['final_mark']
    average/=count
    continue_=input('Continue? y/n')

print(students)
print(average)
```

It 's supposed to run with no problems, however, the output gives me an error:

```
$ python3 FinalMarks.py
student number: 12
Enter test marks: 12 13 12 13 12 13
Continue? y/ny
student number: 13
Enter test marks: 12 14 12 14 12 14
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "FinalMarks.py", line 30, in <module>
    average+=students[student_number]['final_mark']
KeyError: ''
```

My apology if this question seems too easy or stupid to you, but I'm a beginner and I don't have many experiences with dictionaries. Thank you.

Comment: look at the value of student_number when it has that error

Comment: Except for some syntax error in `global student_number = input(student number: ')` which should be `global student_number` and `student_number = input('student number: ')` your code works.

Comment: nutmeg64 Oh, it was a simple and stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
students={}
student_number= ''
grades = {"A":lambda x: x >= 80 and x <= 100, "B":lambda x: x>= 65 and x < 80, "C": lambda x: x >= 55 and x < 65, "D": lambda x:x >= 50 and x < 55, "F":lambda x: x >=0 and x < 50}
def main():
    global student_number
    number = input('student number: ')
    student_number = number
    test_marks=[int(n) for n in input('Enter test marks: ').split()]
    stats = [0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.15, 0.15, 0.1]
    students[student_number]={}
    students[student_number]['final_mark']= sum(a*b for a, b in zip(stats, test_marks))
    grade = [a for a, b in grades.items() if b(students[student_number]['final_mark'])]
    if not grades:
        print("please enter valid grades as listed")
    else:
        print("grade is {}".format(grade[0]))



count=1
continue_=input('Continue? y/n')    
while continue_.lower() == 'y':
   average=0
   main()
   count+=1
   average+=students[student_number]['final_mark']
   average/=count
   continue_=input('Continue? y/n')
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "FinalMarks_.py", line 3, in <module>
    grades = {"A":lambda x: x >= 80 and x <= 100, "B": x>= 65 and x < 80, "C": x >= 55 and x < 65, "D": x >= 50 and x < 55, "F":x >=0 and x < 50}
NameError: name 'x' is not defined

Comment: @ChristianTemple please see my recent edit.

Comment: 'grades' is not  boolean object, so what does 'if not grades' mean?

Comment: Also, in "print("grade is {}".format(grade[0]))", what does "format" mean?

Comment: @ChristianTemple regarding your first question, Python has something called truthy values. That means anything can be checked to see if it is "true". An empty list in Python is considered False, along with an empty string, and the integer value zero. In this case, if any empty list is found, it can be assumed that the user did not enter a correct value. `format` allows you create strings by inserting values into the target string more effectively.